# Comment « coq » a-t-il evolué pour signifier « coquet »?

Tags: étymologie

> [ [Etymonline :](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=coquet&allowed_in_frame=0) ] "amorous, flirtatious person," 1690s, originally of both sexes (as it was in French), from French *coquet* (17c.), diminutive of *coq* "cock" (see [cock](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cock&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.1)). **A figurative reference to its strut or its lust.** The distinction of fem. coquette began c. 1700, and use in reference to males has faded out since.

Je ne comprends pas la phrase en gras : à titre du coq,

1. sa démarche fière ('strut' en anglais) ne me paraît ni amoureuse ni séductrice ni affectueuse ?
2. éveille-t-il un désir sexuel ('lust' en anglais) toujours ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le coq se distingue de la poule par son plumage bariolé, ses couleurs vives, ses plumes longes et brillantes, sa crête imposante.

La vivacité des couleurs et la force de son cri sont des signes biologiques qui attirent la poule : plus les couleurs sont vives, plus les plumes sont longues et peuvent se gonfler, plus le cris est puissant, meilleure sera sa descendance.

Un homme utilisera les mêmes stratagèmes d'habillement, de parade pour séduire, *[il fera le coq](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/faire%20le%20coq)*, il fera le beau en se rengorgeant, en se parant de somptueux atours, il sera donc ***coq***uet.

N.B. : le coq est battu par le paon dans la longueur des plumes, mais si "faire le paon" est encore plus péjoratif (notion de vanité poussée à l'extrême) que "faire le coq" (qui est plus dans la vantardise, dans la concurrence entre mâles), il n'y a pas de diminutif en 'paonnet', car ce n'est pas à l'origine un animal de nos régions, alors que chaque ferme traditionnelle a toujours eu au moins un coq dans la basse-cour.